# Python: How to have the content of a list three times in a new list?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this list

```
QP_list = [50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22]
```

I want to create a new list that contains 3 times the content of this `QP_list`, like

```
new_QP_list = [50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22, 50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22, 50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22]
```

Comment: Have you tried `QP_list*3`?

Comment: @AleksandarMakragić No, thanks! It's working!!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiple the list by how many times you want it!

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x*3 # y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Just do the following:

```
QP_list = [50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22]
new_qp_list = QP_list*3
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Aleksandar mentions, QP_list*3 works in this case.

```
QP_list = [50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22]
new_QP_list = QP_list*3
print new_QP_list
>>> [50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22, 50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22, 50, 46, 42, 38, 34, 30, 26, 22]
```